# How to build URL with AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

AsyncHttpClient provides only a simple [example](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client#sending-requests) where the target URL already prebuilt and represented as a string literal:

```
Future<Response> whenResponse = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://www.example.com/").execute();
```

But what about more complex scenarios where you have to deal with REST endpoints like this, for example:

```
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors
```

How can you specify the base URL in AsyncHttpClient and how you can write code to consume this type of REST services?

P.S. Feign [provides](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#basics) a very convenient way to design your code around REST services your application is about to consume

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using. It has issues but it works for now.

```
public final class ApiHelper {
...
public static Uri UriGet(String baseUrl, String endpoint) {
    //org.apache.http.client.utils
    URIBuilder uriBuilder = null;
    //java.net
    URI uriTemp = null;
    try {
        uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(baseUrl);
        uriTemp = uriBuilder.setPath(Paths.get(uriBuilder.getPath(), endpoint).toString())
                .build()
                .normalize();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //org.asynchttpclient.uri.
    Uri uri = Uri.create(uriTemp.toString());
    return uri;
}

//usage:
String endpoint = "{owner}/{repo}/contributors".replace("{owner}", owner).replace("{repo}", repo);
Uri uri = ApiHelper.UriGet(Baseurl, endpoint);
```